# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [App\Http\Controllers\FileController\FileController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, routes

**This is my web.php file and i have used the correct get and post methods and have specified the path correctly**
<?php

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  
    
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    
    Route::post('store', [FileController::class,'store']); 
    Route::view('imgupload','imageUpload');
```

**blade file--imageUplods;where i get like 2 images and store it as a multiple entry in  the db**

```
<form method="post" action="store" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

    <div class="input-group realprocode control-group lst increment" >
      <input type="file" name="filenames" class="myfrm form-control" id="filenames">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button"> <i class="fldemo glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> 
 </i>Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clone hide">
      <div class="realprocode control-group lst input-group" 
      style="margin-top:10px">
        <input type="file" name="filenames" class="myfrm form-control" 
         id="filenames">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fldemo 
      glyphicon glyphicon-remove"> 
   </i> Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="margin- 
 top:10px">Submit</button>
 
</form>
</div>
```

**model: filemodel -  filesnames is the only attribute to enter**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class file extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;

   protected $fillable = [
       'filenames'
   ];

   public function setFilenamesAttribute($value)
   {
       $this->attributes['filenames'] = json_encode($value);
   }
}
```

**Controller-FileController- imageUploder is the blade file**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class FileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('imageUpload');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
                'filenames' => 'required',
                'filenames.*' => 'image'
        ]);

        $files = [];
        if($request->hasfile('filenames'))
         {
            foreach($request->file('filenames') as $file)
            {
                $name = time().rand(1,100).'.'.$file->extension();
                $file->move(public_path('files'), $name);
                $files[] = $name;
            }
         }

         $file= new File();
         $file->filenames = $files;
         $file->save();

        return redirect('imageUpload')->with('success', 'Your images has 
         been successfully added');
           }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up 'use' and 'namespace'. 'namespace' is for defining the namespace of the current class

Change this line

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
```

to

```
use App\Http\Controllers\FileController;
```

Comment: i get this when i change it to use                                                                                    
     Sorry! Here have some issue please check

The filenames field is required......

Comment: That means your route works now, but you get a validation error...

Comment: You have 2 inputs that have the name filenames. The second input will overwrite the first. Note that they both have the same ID, A id must be unique for the document. If you want to upload multiple files, you can use name="filenames[]". You can do that with one field with the 'multiple' attribute. Your hidden clone element is inside the form, so that field is posted too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change what Gert said about the namespace in `web.php`
2. Change

```
class file extends Model
```

to

```
class File extends Model
```

Comment: web.php doen't have a namespace. The naming for the File class needs to change idd.

Comment: changed the file class name to"File"